# What is the best way to package a Ruby on Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rubygems

So I have created a ruby on rails application that functions as a basic calculator. Now I want to package this application up, upload to github, download onto Jenkins, and create a Jenkins job that will run this ruby application.

Normally if this was a Java Application, you would package it as a jar file and then run the jar file. What would I package this Ruby application as?

I thought about packaging this application as a Ruby Gem, but aren't Ruby Gems mainly for when you want to use your ruby app inside of another ruby application? I want to run this app as a stand alone application.

Even if I were to package the Ruby on Rails app as a Ruby Gem, how would I run the gem as a stand alone gem? What would be the command to run it as such from the command line?

Comment: you should probably look in jRuby implementation that you can run on JVM. Otherwise rails apps are not packaged as java apps, but rather ran by a web server like Unicorn or Passenger

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me. I'm not trying to package my ruby app as a Java app. I simply made the comparison to Java apps and Jar files so that people would understand the kind of file I'm trying to package the ruby application as and ask if there is a ruby equivalent of a Jar file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Java applications that have packaging as a first class citizen(be it a jar or a war) this concept isn't baked in most development environments.

That's why there a big push towards docker, it allows you to insulate your app(and gem dependencies) and plug it into the production environment much like dropping a war into a container.

Here's an article about dockerizing a Rails app:
https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: Thanks for the article! I do have some questions though. I am looking through the article and it shows them using a Ruby on Rails application. Did they package the rails application as a gem or did they start using it immediately without packaging the file. Also how would I use this dockerized application in conjunction with Jenkins? If you recall the end goal was to run this ruby application from a Jenkins job. How would I run a dockerized app in Jenkins?

Comment: In a development environment you can use the embed server in the rails gem by using `rails server` but in production you should build a docker image which is going to be executed by the docker container. The docker container is a manager of virtualized processes. 

 Jenkins has a plugin that provides docker support. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin

Answer (score 1):

Jarbler packs a Ruby app into a self executing jar file including its Gem dependencies

```
> gem install jarbler
> cd app_dir
> jarble        # create the jar file with jRuby runtime
```

The application can then be started without needing a jRuby environment by:

```
> java -jar AppName.jar
```

If you want to change the configuration (Defaults are for a Rails app), generate and adjust a config file by

```
> jarble config
```

See also: https://github.com/rammpeter/jarbler